# Can't see how to run vi having installed it (I want Vi to run Vi not Vim)

Tags: homebrew, vi

I am trying to run Vi (not Vim), because i'm curious about some older commands like `:open`.

I saw this

https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/1u0q0b/how_to_install_traditional_vi_not_vim_on_os_x/

it mentions

http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/

and

`brew install ex-vi`

So I did that brew line.

Then when I tried to run vi,  `$vi<ENTER>` I ran :help and it said Vim!

So I did `$which vi<ENTER>` and it showed `/usr/local/bin/vi`

I did this

```
Apples-MBP:~ apple$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/vi
lrwxr-xr-x  1 apple  admin  29  8 Aug 03:32 /usr/local/bin/vi -> ../Cellar/ex-vi/050325/bin/vi
```

So it looks like it should be running ex-vi but it's not it's running vim. I can't see why?

I tried [Running VI on Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21899/running-vi-on-lion)  and it mentions about getting vim to run like vi, but I want vi itself.

I don't entirely trust vim's compatibility mode (vim -Cu NONE), as presenting vi. (like in vim's compatibility mode I see multiple layers of undo with ctrl-r), which I heard that vi doesn't have.  So I don't want Vim compatibility mode, I want Vi.  I installed it but it isn't running.

How can I run vi and why isn't it running?

Comment: Have you tried running `vi` from a new shell?

Comment: @LawrenceVelázquez ah I think you're right